# Subsurface Modelling method And Advice (PS4 joystick)

Tags: modeling

I tried to venture into subsurface modelling to start practising and gain more knowledge. My aim 
was to try using the tools and methods which I have learnt the past 6 months learning Blender. 
So my final result doesn't look the best. So I wanted some advice what would be the proper or correct
method to have had a better result of this PlayStation control.

The initial top sample had less loop cuts which gave a better shape and clean mesh, but the more I was adding loops to get the bevelled circle bumps the more unclean it would look resulting in bad topology.

So what would be a better method to get a better result?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I'm not a hardsurface nerd, and it's hard to judge if you display the subsurf effect, it doesn't seem too bad, but are you sure you need so many edge loops on the side + so many vertices for your tiny holes? Also, for different pieces like buttons you could create different meshes

Comment: I tried to use more edge loops to achieve the protruding mesh (circle shape) which has the controls functions in it. I found it a challenge to model it which seems to blend in with the side of the control.
https://ibb.co/WWfB0Mw

Comment: ok, so the real object is much rounder than your mesh

Comment: Yes its round, but the technical part I guess is how it wraps around from the front to the side. I found it hard to get those round parts which have the controls without adding loops. I was did use the add on tool, adding circle to get a perfect circle, but once I started adding more loop cuts, it started to deform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should begin with the top face as a blueprint (try to follow the shape as much as possible so that you'll easily add edge loops if needed), then extrude up to give its volume, move the edge loops, etc, like that:

[image]

But you can also begin directly in 3D, roughly model the whole shape, then use the knife to bring details and additional edge loops:

[image]

Comment: Did you first trace the perimeter, then added the inner circles joining the vertices?

Comment: I first create all the circles for the buttons + button zone. In my opinion for this kind of object it's easier to work this way than beginning with a cube, edge loop + extrude it, etc... but some must feel comfortable with this latter approach

Comment: If I began with a cube, once I have the whole shape about good, I would use the knife to draw the button zone

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Ill be practising using these initial instructions.

Comment: there was a quite similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177845/rounded-shapes-with-hard-surface-modeling/177890#177890