# How to bevel these edges cleanly?

Tags: edges, bevel

Im struggling with this bevel, and so if anyone has the time to take a look I'd really appreciate it. Im trying to relicate the bevel on these edges:
[image]

For reference, it is meant to look like this:

[image]

However with the edges so close towards the far left/right, it seems to be impossible to achieve the same effect as in reality.

Answer (score 3):

You could create the basic shape:

[image]

First bevel this part:

[image]

Then bevel all the other edges:

[image]

Then give some corrections:

[image]

Comment: Been learning this lesson recently.  Start big and whittle down.

Comment: it works for modeling and sculpting in Blender at least  ^^

Comment: sometimes it's better to work the other way around, for example for the PS4 joystick I thought it was better to begin with the buttons, as they will determine the amount of necessary vertices: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178043/subsurface-modelling-method-and-advice-ps4-joystick