# Modeling a detergent bottle

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

[image]Im curious what the best approach to modeling this....during the blockout, what areas should be addressed first?  Im using the mira tools plug in (mira curves tool) to handle the curves.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/253199/how-to-create-this-3d-recipient https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177845/rounded-shapes-with-hard-surface-modeling-lubricant-bottle https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55635/making-rounded-dips-in-cylinder

Comment: In the first link shared by Duarte I've added an answer for your bottle